# Quarkus prometheus percentiles still zeroed after long metrics update time

Tags: quarkus, micrometer

I have a service bean MonitoringRegistryServiceImpl implementation in the Quarkus which I used to register timers and update them (code bellow). They were registered only once (into map timerMap) and then reused when recording / updating their values.

The problem I had that if I called http://localhost:8080/q/metrics to see the current state of percentile metrics I saw only zero values.

This happens only after long time period (e.g.3 hours without update of metrics). So far so good, that is something I would expect as there is distributionStatisticExpiry(Duration.ofMinutes(5)) for the percentiles. Let's call it "natural decay of values" :)

However, if I would updated the metrics and then called the http://localhost:8080/q/metrics again the zero values on percentiles were still there yet related counters and max values were updated correctly.

Maybe my understanding of percentiles is not complete, please advice.

Note: I use quarkus-micrometer-registry-prometheus artifact.

```
@JBossLog
@ApplicationScoped
public class MonitoringRegistryServiceImpl implements MonitoringRegistryService {

    private static final double[] PERCENTILES = { 0.5, 0.75, 0.95, 0.99 };
    private Map<String, Timer> timerMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    
    @Inject
    MeterRegistry registry;

    @Override
    public <T> void updateTimer(String timerName, String[] tags,
            Duration duration) {
        String key = timerName + "_" + String.join(".", tags);
        Timer timer = timerMap.get(key);

        if (timer != null) {
            log.debug("Key found:" + key);
            timer.record(duration);
        } else {
            log.debug("Key not found:" + key);
            Timer newTimer = Timer.builder(timerName).tags(newTags).publishPercentiles(PERCENTILES)
                    .distributionStatisticExpiry(Duration.ofMinutes(5))
                    .register(registry);
            timerMap.put(key, newTimer);
            newTimer.record(duration);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This is kind of an awkward way to register timers… you are effectively duplicating the accounting that Micrometer already does. More typical is to use a MeterFilter to configure/enable statistics for timers matching some qualifier, and otherwise use the TimerBuilder to register/record durations. That doesn’t explain why the values are zero. Can you clarify versions of quarkus and micrometer in use?

Comment: Hi, quarkus and quarkus-micrometer-registry-prometheus had the version 1.13.6.Final. I was interested in percentiles therefore I used that approach above yet if there was more "standard" way of doing so with the percentiles please point me to the right direction.

Comment: Interesting stuff that MeterFilter I will have a look.

Comment: This is just an update on new quarkus version. I have switched from the quarkus 1.13.6.Final to the 2.4.2.Final the problem was still there.

Comment: I really don't know what would cause this. Could you open an issue (against either quarkus or micrometer) with a minimal reproducer? That would allow us to sort it out.

Comment: Ok, finally I got time to write some simple reproducer. Details to simulate problems are in README.md https://github.com/mettwm/quarkus-tcpserver

Answer (score 0):

**The solution** was quite simple, rather than using the `Timer.builder()..register()` just use `registry.timer()`. There was also no need for the `timerMap` above. After this change, the timers metrics were not zeroed.

```
Timer timer = registry.timer(timerName, tags);
if (duration != null) {
    timer.record(duration);
} else {
    log.error("Time duration was equal to null for a metric with a timerName:" + timerName);
}
```